# Getting a top 20 list with uniq IP-ranges of SSH attackers and sort them with .0 on the end. Possible?

Tags: regex, sorting, grep, uniq

I hope I can explain this well. I will do my best. As there are many similar questions like this and examples, none of them fill the bill for what I am looking for. I am trying to remove these so-called "attackers" from my servers.

What I am looking for:

- The list should be sorted; let's say a top 20
- The list should be uniq; with a list of unique IP-ranges
- The list should only display the IP's with a 0 on the end

So for example, we have the following IP's in my log:

```
122.155.223.48
116.110.220.28
116.110.220.166
116.196.94.108
118.70.113.1
116.110.220.94
116.110.220.34
118.70.113.2
125.19.37.226
```

Now I need a list which displays them like this:

```
4x 116.110.220.0
2x 118.70.113.0
1x 116.196.94.0
1x 122.155.223.0
1x 125.19.37.0
```

As you can see it merges the last octect (?) to 0 and sorts them by amount of hits.
That way I can block the complete range on my 3 servers.

#### Which logs and what string to look for?

I want to scan all /var/log/secure logs on the server for the above list, this will include (examples): secure, secure-20191124, secure-20191201, etc.

The string to look for is: **Failed password for**

The code I am using so far is:

```
grep "Failed password for" /var/log/secure | grep -Po "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" | sort | uniq -c
```

This works partially, however it does not sort the 20 IP's, it does not sort them with the last octect being .0 (and merges those IP's) and furthermore it does not sort them on the top hits (just random).

Anyways got a working solution for this?

Thanks in advance for your kind help!

#### UPDATE

The provided solution from Thibaud Ledent works very well in the above scenario, but it's not working if the secure logs are displaying entries like this:

```
Dec 18 19:24:58 serverc1 sshd[14698]: refused connect from 212.69.19.250 (212.69.19.250)
Dec 18 19:25:03 serverc1 sshd[14699]: refused connect from 197.51.144.150 (197.51.144.150)
Dec 18 19:42:52 serverc1 sshd[14700]: refused connect from 113.225.182.207 (113.225.182.207)
Dec 18 19:42:52 serverc1 sshd[14701]: refused connect from 113.225.182.207 (113.225.182.207)
Dec 18 20:56:23 serverc1 sshd[14711]: refused connect from 41.176.150.253 (41.176.150.253)
Dec 18 20:59:28 serverc1 sshd[14714]: refused connect from 95.110.201.243 (95.110.201.243)
Dec 18 21:22:46 serverc1 sshd[14722]: refused connect from 107.189.10.44 (107.189.10.44)
Dec 19 00:04:15 serverc1 sshd[15134]: refused connect from 83.97.20.49 (83.97.20.49)
Dec 19 01:52:03 serverc1 sshd[15156]: refused connect from 27.78.12.22 (27.78.12.22)
Dec 19 01:52:05 serverc1 sshd[15157]: refused connect from 27.78.12.22 (27.78.12.22)
Dec 19 01:52:16 serverc1 sshd[15158]: refused connect from 27.78.14.83 (27.78.14.83)
Dec 19 01:52:20 serverc1 sshd[15159]: refused connect from 27.78.12.22 (27.78.12.22)
Dec 19 01:52:20 serverc1 sshd[15160]: refused connect from 27.78.12.22 (27.78.12.22)
Dec 19 01:52:21 serverc1 sshd[15161]: refused connect from 27.78.14.83 (27.78.14.83)
Dec 19 01:52:22 serverc1 sshd[15162]: refused connect from 27.78.14.83 (27.78.14.83)
Dec 19 01:52:24 serverc1 sshd[15163]: refused connect from 27.78.12.22 (27.78.12.22)
Dec 19 01:52:30 serverc1 sshd[15168]: refused connect from 27.78.14.83 (27.78.14.83)
Dec 19 01:52:32 serverc1 sshd[15169]: refused connect from 27.78.14.83 (27.78.14.83)
Dec 19 02:04:58 serverc1 sshd[15189]: refused connect from 195.24.207.252 (195.24.207.252)
Dec 19 02:22:38 serverc1 sshd[15192]: refused connect from 65.49.20.66 (65.49.20.66)
Dec 19 05:04:25 serverc1 sshd[15244]: refused connect from 45.227.255.48 (45.227.255.48)
Dec 19 05:28:09 serverc1 sshd[15247]: refused connect from 203.162.150.234 (203.162.150.234)
Dec 19 05:28:12 serverc1 sshd[15248]: refused connect from 203.162.150.234 (203.162.150.234)
Dec 19 05:31:48 serverc1 sshd[15249]: refused connect from 125.160.17.32 (125.160.17.32)
Dec 19 09:09:06 serverc1 sshd[15297]: refused connect from 139.162.122.110 (139.162.122.110)
Dec 19 09:09:12 serverc1 sshd[15298]: refused connect from 139.162.122.110 (139.162.122.110)
Dec 19 09:54:55 serverc1 sshd[15299]: refused connect from 45.33.70.146 (45.33.70.146)
Dec 19 09:55:00 serverc1 sshd[15300]: refused connect from 45.33.70.146 (45.33.70.146)
Dec 19 09:55:06 serverc1 sshd[15301]: refused connect from 45.33.70.146 (45.33.70.146)
Dec 19 09:55:11 serverc1 sshd[15302]: refused connect from 45.33.70.146 (45.33.70.146)
Dec 19 09:55:16 serverc1 sshd[15303]: refused connect from 45.33.70.146 (45.33.70.146)
Dec 19 10:11:33 serverc1 sshd[15321]: refused connect from 45.33.70.146 (45.33.70.146)
Dec 19 12:49:55 serverc1 sshd[15463]: refused connect from 66.70.188.152 (66.70.188.152)
Dec 19 12:57:29 serverc1 sshd[15466]: refused connect from 107.189.10.141 (107.189.10.141)
Dec 19 13:18:09 serverc1 sshd[15474]: refused connect from 111.59.92.70 (111.59.92.70)
Dec 19 14:34:03 serverc1 sshd[15484]: refused connect from 120.50.182.178 (120.50.182.178)
```

Obviously I changed his solution to:

```
grep " refused connect from" -r /var/log/secure | grep -oE "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.0" | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | head -n 20
```

But it's not displaying results at all?

Maybe it's because showing IP's twice or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep "Failed password for" -r /var/log/secure | grep -oE "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.0" | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | head -n 20
```

**Details:**

Step 1. Find the lines with "Failed password for" in the folder /var/log/secure:

```
grep "Failed password for" -r /var/log/secure
```

Step 2. Filter the IP's ending with .0:

```
grep -oE "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.0"
```

(or if you want all IP's: `grep -oE "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"`)

Step 3. Count the occurrences:

```
sort | uniq -c
```

Step 4. Sort them with the count number in front:

```
sort -r
```

Step 5. Show the first 20 IP's:

```
head -n 20
```

Comment: Awesome!!! Thank you kindly. I only changed one small things: /var/log/secure to /var/log/secure*

This is really, really useful for me. Finally a way to block those IP's permantly from my servers! Two thumbs up! Also for the detailed explanation!

Comment: Apparently it's not working on a different server where it says: "refused connect from" I am not getting enough results? I will update my main post with updated example.

Comment: sorry for the bother, but can you take another look at my main question. I updated it. For some reason it's not working with the other log. TY

Comment: It is because these new IP's do not end with 0 so the grep in step 2 does not give any results. Here is the updated command `grep "refused connect from" -r /pwd_in_container/test/ | grep -oE "[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" | sort | uniq -c | sort -r | head -n 20`